# Limits and Convergence of sequences in the form of $(k, k^2, 1/k)$

Tags: general-topology, limits, convergence-divergence

I'm dealing with proving the convergence and limits of sequences that are defined by multiple points, such as 
$$ \left(k, k^2, \frac{1}{k}\right) $$ and I'm not sure how to go about doing it. I'm aware of the definitions of limits and convergence, I'm just not sure how to apply the to these types of problems.

Comment: In this case, each component $i$ of your vector $(f_1(k), f_2(k), f_3(k))$ is a scalar-valued function $f_i(k)$ that should converge in the usual sense as $k\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: What does it mean for one of these types of sequences to converge?  Can you state the definition?  Does it just mean that each coordinate converges?  If so, where are you having trouble?

Comment: So if I show that one of the co-ordinates doesn't converge I've successfully shown that the sequence doesn't converge? When I attempted it I came to the conclusion that $$ \frac{\sqrt{k^6+1}}{k^2} < \epsilon $$ since k can't be isolated I've essentially shown it's not convergent?

Comment: For that particular vector sequence we get $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}(k, k^2, 1/k)=(\infty, \infty, 0)$.  Since some components are infinity, we do not say it converges.